# What article should I use?

Tags: word-choice, articles

Is there any article needed for *risk* and *farming business* in the following sentence?

> (A) Risk is an important aspect of (the) farming business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either article in that sentence, and it would be grammatical.

> Risk is an important aspect of **a** farming business.

This is talking about risk on a small-scale; it is saying that a farming business has a lot of inherent risk.

> Risk is an important aspect of **the** farming business.

This is talking about risk on a grander scale; it is saying that the entire farming industry has much risk.

You could also make the sentence more generic by using no article, but, in that case, you would omit the word *business*:

> Risk is an important aspect of farming.

This sentence could apply to a single farm, a single farming business, or the entire farming industry as a whole.

As for *risk*, it's best not to use an article when speaking about risk in general. If you are talking about specific risks, though, use the appropriate article:

> **A** big risk in the farming business is price volatility.
>
> Drought is **the** biggest risk faced by most farmers in this valley.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. wouldn't the sentence *"Risk is an important aspect of a farming business."* mean general statement where it suggests that risk would be an important aspect of any farming business (Not particularly singling out) ?

Comment: @Ajay - You are not wrong.